# Cannot mount LVM Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mount, lvm

I'm kinda new to this LVM thing.
I have a hard disk that I need to mount in order to recover some important files. The hard disk was originally from a Centrix Xenserver.

Here's the output of `fdisk -l` for the disk:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 232,9 GiB, 250059350016 bytes, 488397168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 632C984D-FC9D-4C44-B208-D7BE709FCFA5

Device        Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048   8388641   8386594     4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2   8390656  16777249   8386594     4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda3  16779264 488397134 471617871 224,9G Linux LVM
```

lvscan:

```
$ sudo lvscan
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  Couldn't find device with uuid QIMtBk-31kl-2Hun-tOsy-AgO1-X20n-Q3Tvn2.
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3/MGT' [4,00 MiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3/VHD-100b96bd-dd71-4c78-b8fd-3c9bb7ad6ae2' [100,20 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3/VHD-ee59b325-a97a-48f2-a0b1-7228a0bb59b3' [100,20 GiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3/VHD-203138b3-2d2d-4a25-ad6b-70ebc0936468' [256,00 MiB] inherit
  ACTIVE            '/dev/VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3/VHD-d4cd0880-562d-4f0b-a7bf-86a755f351b3' [16,00 MiB] inherit
```

lvdisplay:

```
$ sudo lvdisplay
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  Couldn't find device with uuid QIMtBk-31kl-2Hun-tOsy-AgO1-X20n-Q3Tvn2.
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3/MGT
  LV Name                MGT
  VG Name                VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3
  LV UUID                5BrqYB-oJkA-DZtI-y0PK-eE0s-gJyS-eTOOT5
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                4,00 MiB
  Current LE             1
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3/VHD-100b96bd-dd71-4c78-b8fd-3c9bb7ad6ae2
  LV Name                VHD-100b96bd-dd71-4c78-b8fd-3c9bb7ad6ae2
  VG Name                VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3
  LV UUID                7C6FGC-LjEb-Dzjx-02Aa-OE0M-zTTk-Z0GxHS
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                100,20 GiB
  Current LE             25652
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3/VHD-ee59b325-a97a-48f2-a0b1-7228a0bb59b3
  LV Name                VHD-ee59b325-a97a-48f2-a0b1-7228a0bb59b3
  VG Name                VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3
  LV UUID                cOtP3z-MEqC-BjMI-EnTB-E3jO-sU01-3I03hD
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                100,20 GiB
  Current LE             25652
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:2

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3/VHD-203138b3-2d2d-4a25-ad6b-70ebc0936468
  LV Name                VHD-203138b3-2d2d-4a25-ad6b-70ebc0936468
  VG Name                VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3
  LV UUID                gx1AhN-Ebx9-yTnz-xWEQ-18F9-19Ct-Xd0h5V
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                256,00 MiB
  Current LE             64
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:3

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3/VHD-d4cd0880-562d-4f0b-a7bf-86a755f351b3
  LV Name                VHD-d4cd0880-562d-4f0b-a7bf-86a755f351b3
  VG Name                VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3
  LV UUID                lmayRw-hJyh-GrXy-hjEU-m7lc-f3XU-F2N9Ar
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time , 
  LV Status              available
  # open                 0
  LV Size                16,00 MiB
  Current LE             4
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:4
```

and vgdisplay:

```
$ sudo vgdisplay
  /run/lvm/lvmetad.socket: connect failed: No such file or directory
  WARNING: Failed to connect to lvmetad. Falling back to internal scanning.
  Couldn't find device with uuid QIMtBk-31kl-2Hun-tOsy-AgO1-X20n-Q3Tvn2.
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  41
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                5
  Open LV               0
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               457,75 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              117184
  Alloc PE / Size       51373 / 200,68 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       65811 / 257,07 GiB
  VG UUID               uuMOc2-J8cU-9fOO-zoda-stQz-xKhh-mjYnd1
```

When I try to mount I get this:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/VG_XenStorage-e87e45db-88b6-fe01-9d35-c19431cee0f3/VHD-100b96bd-dd71-4c78-b8fd-3c9bb7ad6ae2 /media/lvm/
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/mapper/VG_XenStorage--e87e45db--88b6--fe01--9d35--c19431cee0f3-VHD--100b96bd--dd71--4c78--b8fd--3c9bb7ad6ae2,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error

       In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
       dmesg | tail or so.
```

Can anyone please point out what's wrong?
Thanks.